# How to stop self-recursion in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, recursion

There is technique to define class, containing a method, returning a value of the same type as class -- self recursion.

But using this, is it possible to stop recursion?

Some code:

```
public class StopSelfRecursion {

   // base class
   static class Class1<Self extends Class1<Self,T>, T> {
      public Self getMyself() {
         return (Self) this;
      }
   }

   // derived 1
   static class Class2<Self extends Class2<Self, T>, T> extends Class1<Self, T> {
   }

   // derived 2
   static class Class3<Self extends Class2<Self, T>, T> extends Class2<Self, T> {
   }

   // want to stop recursion; want Class4 has only one parameter
   static class Class4<T> extends Class3<Class3, T> {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Class1<?, Integer> v1 = new Class1<>();

      Class2<?, Integer> v2 = new Class2<>();

      Class3<?, Integer> v3 = new Class3<>();

      System.out.println(v1.toString());
      System.out.println(v2.toString());
      System.out.println(v3.toString());


   }
}
```

If it is not possible to stop recursion, then why?

If there is no logic reason of being not able to stop it, then what about adding this feature in next versions of Java?

For example, keyword `ThisClass` can be added or something.

Comment: Could you post an actual example of this recursion technique you claim exists?  I have a feeling that the example you show here misses the point.

Comment: The `(Self) this` cast is unsafe. `Self` is declared to extend `Class1<Self,T>`, but `this` (which is of type `Class1<Self,T>`) is not necessarily a `Self`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what the issue is, beyond fixing the compilation issue.  You can do that by simply changing the definition of `Class4` to this:

```
static class Class4<T> extends Class3<Class4<T>, T>
                                         ^^
```

[*[Live example](http://ideone.com/x8CL7n)*]